# Convert single page HTML to Angular 11

Tags: html, angular, routes, sections, onepage-scroll

I have created single-page HTML for the website.  I have added section tags to differentiate sections. Sections are scroll while scrolling and when clicking on any link from the top menu it will scroll on a specific ection. Below is my HTML code.

```
    <div id="pagepiling" class="wrapper">
    <section id="home"
        class="navbar-is-white text-dark pp-scrollable d-flex align-items-center section position-absolute home-bg"
        role="main">
        <div class="intro">
            <div class="scroll-wrap">
                <div class="container">                       
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="about" class="section pp-scrollable d-flex align-items-center position-absolute">
        <div class="intro">
            <div class="scroll-wrap">
                <div class="container">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </section>
    <section id="service" class="section pp-scrollable d-flex align-items-center position-absolute">
        <div class="intro">
            <div class="scroll-wrap">
                <div class="container">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </section>
    <section id="career" class="section pp-scrollable d-flex align-items-center position-absolute">
        <div class="intro">
            <div class="scroll-wrap">
                <div class="container">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </section>
    <section id="contact" class="section pp-scrollable d-flex align-items-center position-absolute">
        <div class="intro">
            <div class="scroll-wrap">
                <div class="container">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </section>
</div>
```

I have created an Angular 11 app and I have enabled routing in that app. Now, need to migrate the above code in this app. So, I have created the Angular 11 app and implement my HTML code. But all sections come one on one instead of below as per the sequence.

Comment: you should take a look to the docs about routing:https://angular.io/guide/routing-overview, in brief, you has a "menu" using a serie of  `<a routerLink="/path" routerLinkActive="active">` and one `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. Each component defined in "Routes" are "inserted" in the '<router-outlet>'  when you click in the router-link.

Comment: I have created the Angular11 app and implement my HTML code. But all sections come one on one instead of below as per the sequence.